# Calculating the X and Z position of a vertex (within a mesh) using gl_VertexID

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to generate 3D terrain. My goal is to pass the vertex shader the height of the vertex, and calculate the x and the z position from within the vertex shader using `gl_VertexID`. Vertices are 1 apart on the x and z axis. Here is the vertex shader:

```c
#version 330 core

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 world;

layout(location = 0) in float height;

// vertex offset; position of vertex relative to the top left corner of square
const vec2 offset[6] = vec2[](
    vec2(0, 0), // top left
    vec2(0, 1), // bottom left
    vec2(1, 1), // bottom right
    vec2(1, 1), // bottom right
    vec2(0, 0), // top left
    vec2(1, 0)  // top right
);

void main() {
    // index of square
    int squareIndex = gl_VertexID / 6;
    // index of vertex within square
    int vertexIndex = gl_VertexID % 6;

    // xz position of vertex
    vec2 position = offset[vertexIndex] + vec2(squareIndex % LENGTH, squareIndex / LENGTH);

    gl_Position = projection * view * world * vec4(position.x, height, position.y, 1.0f);
}
```

Triangles are drawn left to right, top to bottom. Here is the generation of the EBO:

```
for(unsigned int xSquare = 0; xSquare < LENGTH; xSquare++) {
   for(unsigned int zSquare = 0; zSquare < LENGTH; zSquare++) {
      size_t squareIndex = zSquare * LENGTH + xSquare;
      unsigned int topLeft = squareIndex;
      unsigned int topRight = squareIndex + 1;
      unsigned int bottomLeft = squareIndex + LENGTH;
      unsigned int bottomRight = squareIndex + LENGTH + 1;
      elements[squareIndex] = topLeft;
      elements[squareIndex + 1] = bottomLeft;
      elements[squareIndex + 2] = bottomRight;
      elements[squareIndex + 3] = bottomRight;
      elements[squareIndex + 4] = topLeft;
      elements[squareIndex + 5] = topRight;
   }
}
```

I've checked the vertex data input using qrenderdoc, and the heights are being passed to the vertex shader properly. However,
[the rendered output looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lKNB.png)

[image]

I've checked over the vertex shader logic, and I haven't been able to find any issues. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take care not to confuse the index buffer (sometimes known as the element buffer) with the vertex buffer. Note that `gl_VertexID` is the "index of the vertex", not the "index of the index". Your shader can simply do:

```
int row = gl_VertexID / LENGTH;
int col = gl_VertexID % LENGTH;
```

By the way, when you're building the index buffer, you should ensure that the orientation of each triangle pair is consistent. Right now it looks like one is clockwise and the other is counter-clockwise. Play with GL_CULL_FACE to see how this can affect things.

Just air coding here, but I'd do something like this:

```cpp
unsigned int elementIndex = 0;
for(unsigned int zSquare = 0; zSquare < LENGTH - 1; zSquare++) {
   for(unsigned int xSquare = 0; xSquare < LENGTH - 1; xSquare++) {
      size_t vertexIndex = zSquare * LENGTH + xSquare;
      unsigned int topLeft = vertexIndex;
      unsigned int topRight = vertexIndex + 1;
      unsigned int bottomLeft = vertexIndex + LENGTH;
      unsigned int bottomRight = vertexIndex + LENGTH + 1;
      elements[elementIndex++] = topLeft;
      elements[elementIndex++] = bottomLeft;
      elements[elementIndex++] = bottomRight;
      elements[elementIndex++] = bottomRight;
      elements[elementIndex++] = topRight;
      elements[elementIndex++] = topLeft;
   }
}
```

While using `gl_VertexID` seems clever, simply including X and Y in the vertex buffer is a simpler alternative, and will make it easier to extend your code in the future if you want to be smarter about the terrain tessellation (e.g. perhaps you'll want to use larger triangles in flat areas).